# Get all data from JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I've a little problem with a simple thing.I believe.
this is my code...

[javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8A8D.png)

I'm able to grab the first object element but I need all the data object, I guess I've to change something in this code line...

```
value[0]['firstName'];
```

Comment: Please post your code not only image.

Comment: `gennaio` is an array. You will have to loop over it as well. Also, Its a bad practice to append inside a loop. Create an html string and append it to this string and at the end, set this string.

Comment: @Rajesh can you show me how to do this with a short example ?! Thank you

Comment: @EliaMarotta If you put your code instead of snapshot, there are many smarter people than me than can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
value[0]['firstName'];  // $.each()
```

With

```
value[index]['firstName'];   // $.each()
```

And

```
$.each(oggprova.PIANIFI,function(){...});
```

with

```
$.each(oggprova.PIANIFI.gennio,function(){....});
```

Comment: I tried but does't work !

Comment: can you provide code not image only?

Comment: the code is here https://jsfiddle.net/2s32jdc2/ in result on the right bottom panel I want to get the results of array.... not the gennaio / [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]